# Remote DB connection to SQL Server 18 (single sign on) using PgAdmin

Tags: sql-server, single-sign-on, remote-access, pgadmin

I am currently trying to figure out the best way to do a remote database connection via windows server that has SQL Server 18 database (single sign on), and I am wanting to use a tool to help parse the data, like PgAdmin.

We have a server here in our building, that we have to use Windows based remote connection, which stores the SQL Server 18 in it, that holds the data that I need.

I am needing to get that data, to my PC (not connected to the server so I can't make edits on the main server ((read only access))), and need to create my own Schema to generate the reports/information that I am in need of.

Any help with this would be greatly appreciated.

Thank you in advance!

My boss has attempted to do this in the past, I am not completely sure of what methods he used, but he was unsuccessful at it.

Comment: There's no such thing as `sqlserver 18`

Comment: I'm a little confused by the details but generally speaking on windows with sql server you can use SSMS (and many other similar tools) to connect to a database and read data (run queries, view tables, etc.) https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/ssms/download-sql-server-management-studio-ssms

Comment: If you are using SQL Server 18, that might well be your problem; no drivers for it exist yet. I don't expect them to be released until SQL Server 18 is released, which is probably sometime between 2026-2028. You're using an incredibly early pre-release build (or you have access to a time machine).

Comment: @ThomA -- I just verified and we are actually using SQL Studio Management vs 14.0.2052.1

Comment: The version of SSMS is irrelevant, @Felecia , we need to know the version of SQL Server. What does `PRINT @@VERSION` return?

Comment: SQL Server Management Studio (SSMS) is the equivalent for PgAdmin for Microsoft SQL Server. Does that answer your question?